# Display image in Asp.net web application using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, image

I am trying to display an image in my Asp.net web application. I am using JavaScript to do this.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "~/Images/Key.PNG";
$('#sidebar').append(img);
```

This is the code I am using to add the image to the webpage, It tries to add the images as is shows a broken image icon on the page. But I get this error when I 'right click' and view the image.

[image]

And this is the file structure of my Asp.net Web application:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?
I know it something to do with the image location url but not sure what to put.

Comment: Remove the tilde `~` from `img.src`.

Comment: Ive been staring at this for so long, Thanks for the solution :)